# Signification de « maître de compagnie, chefs de portes »

Tags: vocabulaire, groupe-nominal

On m'a demandé ce que signifie :

> maître de compagnie, chefs de portes

Dans le contexte :

> Ils veulent que les dizainiers comme les maîtres de compagnie et chefs de porte devront élire des gens pour 12 personnes.

C'est un contexte plutôt archaïque et du Moyen Âge. Sauriez-vous ce que cela pourrait signifier ?

[image]

L'auteur et le livre sont :
Olivier Christin , Vox Populi

Comment: La question porte-t-elle sur Warhammer 40K?

Comment: @vc74, I don't think so because she told me it is in a Middle Ages context and, although I don't know Warhammer 40K, I see tanks in the Google Image search :)

Comment: @vc74, I managed to get the context. It is definitely not from Warhammer 40K :)

Comment: @OK, un coup dans l'eau alors ;)

Comment: @vc74, yes! Thanks for trying :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il s'agit de grades d'une "milice" ou garde bourgeoise de la ville d'Amiens chargée de surveiller les remparts et portes de la ville.

- Maîtres de compagnies: Dirige un groupe de 100 habitants
- Chef de portes: Dirige 15 hommes (10 portiers et 5 guetteurs)
- Dizainier: Dirige une escouade de dix hommes chargée de surveiller l'un des dix quartiers de la ville.

Note, il ne s'agit plus (en 1563 ou 1598) du Moyen Âge mais du début de la Renaissance.

[Source](https://books.openedition.org/pur/94048?lang=fr): *La milice bourgeoise comme instrument de reconstruction identitaire de la communauté citadine à Amiens, dans le premier tiers du XVIIe siècle*